# Probability with Combinatorics

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

In a cellar there are 3 bottles of wine which are 18 years old, 4 bottles which are 20 years old and 3 more bottles which are 22 years old. Two bottles are being sampled by random. Let X be the average age of the wine (of the two bottles). Find P(X=20). I tried solving this by understanding that there are 10C2 possibilities (number of pairs), and I am interested in 15 of them. It gives me 1/3. I am not sure I am correct. Can you help me with the number of options in the nominator and denominator? Thanks !

Comment: Is it homework? If yes please add `[self-study]` tag and check http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: This isn't home work, just a problem I have encountered and am curious about.

Comment: The number of bottles of each type in your sample follows a multihypergeometric distribution, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution.  The rest follows easily from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct answer on base of multihypergeometric distribution:$$\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{0}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{3}{0}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{0}}{\binom{10}{2}}$$

You can also reason: if I have picked one bottle then how many bottles of the remaining $9$ will lead to $X=20$? In all cases the answer on that is $3$ so the probability equals: $$\frac39=\frac13$$